# Editing an asp.net DropdownList 

Tags: asp.net

I have a dropdown list of 5 elements. My problem is that I want to make this dropdown list editable. Basically a user might want to delete one of these elements or might want to add more elements. Whats a good approach of doing that in asp.net ?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [ComboBox](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/combobox/combobox.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You have to put textbox for typing text and button for user to insert into the list and button for delete
Do you know the code to adding and deleting list in the dropdown list right ?

Comment: yes I know the code to do that. Is their a way to add and delete elements with out having a textbox and 2 buttons . For instance the dropdown list can be edited by clicking on the last element?

Comment: DDL is not the correct control for this scenario... user has to click a button to see the selection options??

Answer (score 0):

Use a ListBox - that way they can make a multi-selection of their choice:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox.aspx

The DropDownList is not intended for multi-selection. Another option would be to use CheckBoxes.

Answer (score 0):

If you use DataBase, u can make dropdownlist MORE editable with elements like "formView", "gridView" and so on..